# From an Eclipse plugin, how can I programmatically cause Eclipse to edit a certain file?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, editor

I have a plugin which creates a new view. In my view I display certain information about certain Java classes in the project. I want to allow the user to double click on a class in my view and when s/he does, I want to open that class for editing in the editor. Basically similarly to what the Hierarchy View does: it displays the tree of classes and when the user double-clicks on one of them, it goes into the editor. How do I do that if what I have is an object of type `IType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be showing a high-level implementation for your requirement. You have to do following steps.

- first you have to do entry in `Plugin.xml` for the class which extends
  `viewPart` and `editorPart` for a view and editor respectively.
- for the hierarchy view, you have to load the information with a tree structure in
  `ViewPart`.
- On a node's double click Listener you have to open the editor.

To open a file in the editor, use the following code to open the editor.

```
 if (fileToOpen.exists() && fileToOpen.isFile()) {
     String path = //Path for that to file to open;
     IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
     URI fromString = org.eclipse.core.runtime.URIUtil.fromString("file://" + path);
     try {
         IEditorPart openEditor = IDE.openEditor(page, fromString, Editor.ID, true);
         IEditorInput editorInput = openEditor.getEditorInput();
         //editorInput.
     } catch ( PartInitException e ) {
         //Put your exception handler here if you wish to.
     }
 }
```

Comment: yesterday, Editor.ID is unresolved and i can't find what's needed to resolve it.  Which Required plug-in, imported package, or extension, do i need to add in order for Editor to be resolved?

Comment: Editor id is the id with which you register your class in plugin.xml, this should be unique to get identify the instance of editor that you want to open

Comment: RTA, thanks, but i want to open a java file in the main eclipse text editor. what's the id of that editor? is there a place where one can check and find out the ID's of all eclipse editors?

Comment: just define a Unique id in your editor class and pass it. for example you have define public static final String ID = "javaEditor"; in class A and reference it now it works i hope.